# TexMaker Line Number Horizontal Space

Tags: texmaker

Is there any way to get the TexMaker line numbers to take up less horizontal space?
There's only 150 lines in this document.
Texmaker 4.1 on Kubuntu 14.04

[image: TexMaker]

Answer (score 3):

You can hide the side bar completely (Options -> Configure Texmaker -> Editor -> Show Line Numbers) but, to my knowledge, you can't change configure the size of the components. The space to the right of the numbers allows for regions to be displayed and the space to the left is for bookmarks (hence the "extra-wide" appearance).